# Lua - How to log nested table access/writes without creating a "proxy" index outside of the metatable?

Tags: lua, metatable

There's a [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58111147/11161500) where you'd be doing something like this to the original table.

```lua
function setproxy(t)
  new_t = {proxy = t}
  setmetatable(new_t, mt)
  return new_t
end
```

However, if you'd be printing out `t`, you'd get this:
`t["proxy"]`.

So I was wondering how to do the nested logging, in this fashion:

```lua
local Settings = {}
Settings.example = "Value"

local proxyTable = setmetatable({}, {
    __index = Settings,
    
    __newindex = function(t, k, v)
        print(t, k, v)
        
        Settings[k] = v
    end,
})

proxyTable.example = "value"
```

With the exception that it supports nesting as well.

It can be a pain to figure out what is going on with this complexity.

So far I had this approach, but I am not sure if it's correct:

```lua
local table1 = {
    table2 = {}
}

local function newProxy(tbl)
    local mt = {}
    mt.__index = tbl
    
    mt.__newindex = function(t, k, v)
        print(t, k, v)

        if (type(v) == "table") then
            v = newProxy(v)
        end

        rawset(t,k,v)
    end
    
    local newProxy = setmetatable(tbl, mt)
    return newProxy
end



local proxyTable = setmetatable({},
{
    __index = table1,

    __newindex = function(t, k, v)
        print(t, k, v)

        if (type(v) == "table") then
            v = newProxy(v)
        end

        rawset(t,k,v)
    end,
})


for k,v in pairs(table1) do
    if (type(v) == "table") then
        v = newProxy(v)
    end
    
    rawset(proxyTable, k, v)
end




proxyTable.table2.a = {val = "value"}
proxyTable.table2.a.b = {a="a"}
proxyTable.table2.a.b.c = "hi"

for k,v in pairs(proxyTable) do
    print(k,v)
end
```

point of the `a.val`

is to test cases, because when I tried to do this, a would have reset back to `{}` if I created a table inside of it.

And it was all depending on `local newProxy = setmetatable(tbl, mt)`. If I'd set it to local newProxy = setmetatable({}, mt), I'd reset `proxyTable.table2.a = {val = "value"}` if I created `proxyTable.table2.a.b = {a="a"}`

That's my current approach. Maybe it's even the correct way, but I don't know.

What I need to know is, whether my approach is still a proxy, or whether by doing this `newProxy = setmetatable(tbl, mt)` if I already broke the purpose.

Because I believe I only need one proxy. And seen that proxyTable, is a proxy for table1. I believe it's already done.

Comment: The correct way is `local newProxy = setmetatable({}, mt)`.  I didn't understand what problem you have (what does "resetting" of `table2.a` mean?).

Comment: since I wanna keep track of everything within that table, including tables. The only way by doing that, is by creating proxies for the nested table as well. but by doing setmetatable({}, mt) on the nested tables, it would reset whatever they contained before, because it gets turned back into {}

Comment: `setmetatable({}, mt)` resets nothing: empty table `{}` does not have a metatable.

Comment: @ESkri If I change ``setmetatable(tbl, mt)`` to ``setmetatable({}, mt)``, the nested table's original value becomes ``{}``, if it contained ``{test="value"}`` before, it would be gone.

The first table can use ``setmetatable({}, mt)``, but I am unsure about tables within that table. I believe only the first table needs to act as a proxy.

Comment: The table get shifted into .__index, using direct print() doesn't return the table. Unless you index in it.

Comment: In your code, you're calling `newProxy` as a function, but later, you're defining `newProxy` as a table. What is `newProxy` really supposed to be?

Comment: @luther That's a shadowed variable. It may be poor semantics, but its technically fine, and does not influence the design (could easily be `return setmetatable(tbl, mt)` instead, however).

Comment: The fact that `newProxy` is being called means we need to see some kind of implementation to make a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and thus understand the problem. From what I can see `newProxy` looks pretty central to the algorithm, so it must be influencing the design somehow.

Comment: @luther The *function* `local function newProxy(tbl)` is clearly defined in the third example, which constitutes the main [mre].

Comment: Ok. the function didn't show up for me until I did a Ctrl+F. I tried scrolling through everything, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

A [proxy](https://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.4.html) needs to be empty, so that all forms of access are intercepted.

In `newProxy`, `setmetatable(tbl, mt)` reuses the existing table `tbl` as its *own* proxy. This means `__newindex` will not fire for existing keys in `tbl`.

You can test this by adding the line

```lua
-- ...
proxyTable.table2.a.b.c = "hi"
proxyTable.table2.a.b.c = "will not be logged" -- this does not invoke __newindex
```

and observing no additional logging.

---

Using [*closures*](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.5) is one way to achieve a proxy that does not contain any metadata.

A few changes to your code yields the following. Note that this function does not handle nested tables in its argument (`tbl`), so the proxy must be built up one level at a time.

```lua
local function newProxy(tbl)
    local mt = {}
    mt.__index = tbl

    mt.__newindex = function(t, k, v)
        print(t, k, v)

        if type(v) == "table" then
            v = newProxy(v)
        end

        rawset(tbl, k, v)
    end

    return setmetatable({}, mt)
end

local proxyTable = newProxy {}
proxyTable.table2 = {}
proxyTable.table2.a = { val = "value" }
proxyTable.table2.a.b = { a ="a" }
proxyTable.table2.a.b.c = "hi"
proxyTable.table2.a.b.c = "this will be logged"

-- note that this no longer works, because it iterates on the (empty) proxy
for k,v in pairs(proxyTable) do
    print(k, v)
end
```

Example output:

```
table: 0x55b9fc7d3f10   table2  table: 0x55b9fc7d3f50
table: 0x55b9fc7d6240   a   table: 0x55b9fc7d6280
table: 0x55b9fc7d6430   b   table: 0x55b9fc7d6470
table: 0x55b9fc7d6620   c   hi
table: 0x55b9fc7d6620   c   this will be logged
```

---

Here is a function that recursively clones tables, and gives each a proxy:

```lua
-- Lua 5.4.6, LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
-- This function returns a proxy to a clone of its argument
-- It does not handle circular references in its argument
local function Proxy(t)
    local actual = {}
    t = t or {}

    local proxy = setmetatable({}, {
        __metatable = false,
        __name = "Proxy",
        __tostring = function (self)
            return string.format("Proxy: %p -> %p(%p)", self, actual, t)
        end,
        __eq = function (self, other)
            -- create a closure around `t` to emulate shallow equality
            return rawequal(t, other) or rawequal(self, other)
        end,
        __pairs = function (self)
            -- wrap `next` to enable proxy hits during traversal
            return function (tab, key)
                local index, value = next(actual, key)

                return index, value ~= nil and self[index]
            end, self, nil
        end,
        -- these metamethods create closures around `actual`
        __len = function (self)
            return rawlen(actual)
        end,
        __index = function (self, key)
            print("LOG: index", self, key)

            return rawget(actual, key)
        end,
        __newindex = function (self, key, value)
            print("LOG: newindex", self, key, "=", value)

            -- Any new table-values are proxied ...
            rawset(actual, key, type(value) == "table" and Proxy(value) or value)
        end
    })

    -- ... recursively
    for key, value in pairs(t) do
        proxy[key] = value
    end

    return proxy
end

--[[ simple usage --]]
-- create a proxy, add values, and access them
-- every read and write is logged
local p = Proxy()
p.foo = { bar = { 'hello world' } }
print(p.foo.bar[1])
print("proxies are immutable: ", not getmetatable(p))
print(select(2, pcall(setmetatable, p, {})))
--]]

--[[ more info:
-- ... or clone existing tables
local foo = Proxy { bar = { qux = { zun = "hello" } } }

-- proxies of tables
local thing = {}
foo.bar.qux.zarb = thing

-- proxies of proxies
foo.bar.qux.plaz = foo.bar.qux.zarb

-- shallow equality holds true ...
print("shallow equality should be true:", foo.bar.qux.zarb == thing)
-- ... but only through one level of proxy
print("transitive equality should be false:", foo.bar.qux.plaz == thing)

-- ... deep equality does not persist (proxies are clones)
thing.x = 51
print("deep equality should be false:", foo.bar.qux.zarb.x == thing.x)

-- length operators and iterators work, `ipairs` triggers `__index` for `#t + 1`
local abc = Proxy { 'a', 'b', 'c' }
print(abc, "has a length of", #abc)

for k, v in ipairs(abc) do
    print(string.format("abc[%s] = %q", k, v))
end
--]]
```

Example output:

```
LOG: newindex   Proxy: 0x556701bbde90 -> 0x556701bbde10(0x556701bbde50) foo =   table: 0x556701bbe0c0
LOG: newindex   Proxy: 0x556701bbe7d0 -> 0x556701bbe790(0x556701bbe0c0) bar =   table: 0x556701bbe100
LOG: newindex   Proxy: 0x556701bbebb0 -> 0x556701bbeb70(0x556701bbe100) 1   =   hello world
LOG: index  Proxy: 0x556701bbde90 -> 0x556701bbde10(0x556701bbde50) foo
LOG: index  Proxy: 0x556701bbe7d0 -> 0x556701bbe790(0x556701bbe0c0) bar
LOG: index  Proxy: 0x556701bbebb0 -> 0x556701bbeb70(0x556701bbe100) 1
hello world
proxies are immutable:  true
cannot change a protected metatable
```